# Is there a way, in Eclipse, to remove deprecated warnings, pre Java 1.5

Tags: java, eclipse

We have an internal Java library, that for legacy reasons, needs to be compiled using Java 1.4.  However, this lib has gone through several versions, the latter of which have had certain methods and objects deprecated.  For client support reasons, the code needs to use some of these deprecated methods/objects.  As such, we always keep the latest lib on the build path of our projects (in Eclipse).

I would like to

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation");
```

Though, do to the aforementioned 1.4 dependency, this is not possible.

Is there a way for me to remove the warnings, if only from my Eclipse Problems view, and somewhat cleanup my development environment?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to remove the warnings, if only from my Eclipse Problems view, and somewhat cleanup my development environment?

You can configure the Java Compiler to ignore the Deprecated Warnings. I'd suggest to configure this setting for the specific project, not globally. To do so, **right-click** on your project and go to **Properties > Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings**. Click **Enable project specific settings** and then unfold **Deprecated and restricted API** and select **Ignore** for **Deprecated API**.

This will disable all deprecated warnings though.

Comment: +1. Clear answer (even if a.yfrog.com is blocked at work by the firewall... hint: imageshack.us is not ;) )

Comment: @VonC Thanks. Regarding yfrog.com, the tool I'm using for screenshots switched to from imageshack.us to it, not me :) But it offers some alternatives. Would imagebanana.com be better?.

Comment: well, at least imagebanana.com is not blocked ;)

Comment: Thank you! My OCD can subside now that the little yellow squigglies have gone away.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not concerned about deprecation *anywhere* in that project, you could always give it custom project compilation settings and set it to ignore deprecation. It's not ideal, but it may well be better for you in this case than living with the deprecation warnings - it means you'll be able to spot ones in your *other* projects more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could treat it as a standalone project. If its legacy you won't need to update often.  In your main project use the JAR created with a link to the source so you still see that.  That way it won't be compiled so it won't create warnings all the time.